# GWT native function - reference per string

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, native

I would like to make references in native javascript based on names in strings in gwt:

```
private String reference = "testFunction";

private native void initTool() /*-{
  $wnd.reference = function(){ 
    //function action
  }
}-*/;
```

The idea then is that i from javascript should be able to run the method like this:

```
window.testFunction();
```

I hope this is possible some how? I havent found anything online explaining this, maybe because i dont know what to search for.

regards

Comment: Did you have a look at this: [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$wnd[this.@my.app.client.MyClass::reference] = function() { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot .

What you can do is pass the String to JavaScript and decide the function name there based upon conditions.